# Seeing CSS margins for debugging

Tags: html, css

I use the following CSS styles to debug where my div and span outlines are (normally keep it commented):

`div { outline: 1px dashed blue } span { outline: 1px dashed green }`

While that shows the outer bounds of divs and spans and gives an idea of padding relative to the object/text inside, it does not help visualize where the margins assigned to the same style are.  I understand the difference between padding and margins but I really need to  be able to see the visual effect when building a page (too much detail, too little attention span).

Is there any way to add an outer rectangle to show where the margins are for a style?

Comment: Why don't you use Firebug or Inspector?

Comment: Now check tothis and tell me what is the problum http://jsfiddle.net/96PjJ/

Comment: @RohitAzad He doesn't have any problem, he needs convenience.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any attribute that allows a border on the outside of margin as that goes against the purpose of what a margin is. [W3's Box Model Explanation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)

While this was a great technique in early web development, I cannot recommend strongly enough taking a few minutes to install Firebug or to familiarize yourself with Chrome's Developer tools, or Safari's "Inspect" features, etc. You can just mouse over code and get far more data than hours of messing around with hand-made debug styling.

You'll love them!

Firebug especially allows mousing over code and it will highlight your main box, color coded padding and margin, etc. An invaluable tool - it's even better than Dreamweaver's built in visual outline tools.

Comment: how do i see margins with Firebug ?  i just tried but couldn't

Comment: Oh, you just turn on Firebug, click on the HTML tab, then choose the Layout tab on the right side. It creates a pretty box to show padding, margin, etc, and enables mouse-over highlighting. Click or mouse over your relevant html code on the left side and it will show you the measurements on the right and highlight/color-code live in the site view above.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't. I would recommend either using Chrome's Dev tools or Firebug as previously mentioned. A nice perk you get with those tools, is the ability to manipulate the DOM on the fly. This makes testing out placement very quick and painless. Sometimes if I'm trying to place a div juuust right, I'll right-click the div, select inspect this element, and then look at the properties on the right-hand side. You can actually adjust these real-time and see the changes reflected in the page. A nice trick is that many of the properties allow you to use the up and down arrow keys to cycle through their values. This makes adjusting the margin-left or a margin-right value a cinch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my new tool for this.  You mouse over any element in your page and it will show you all parts of its layout (margin, border, padding, etc.).

[HTML Box Visualizer - GitHub](https://github.com/ghmcadams/boxvis)